# In SystemC why cant a wait be put in SC_METHOD?

Tags: systemc

I was going through some tutorial on SystemC and there was a mention that we cant put wait in SC_METHOD, it didn't explain why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because `SC_METHOD` [does not have its own thread of execution](http://asic-dv.com/index.php/systemc/scmethodandscthread). Every time an event on an `SC_METHOD` sensitivity list is triggered, the `SC_METHOD`'s code is (ideally) entirely executed. In other words, calling `wait()` in an `SC_METHOD` would freeze the simulation itself.

In contrast, an `SC_THREAD` has its own thread of execution and its activity is  generally modeled inside a loop containing or not `wait()` statements, which pauses the execution of the thread. Whenever an event (of the sensitivity list) is triggered, the execution is resumed at the command that follows the previously issued `wait()`.

Answer (score 2):

Its a feature of the language. SC_METHOD is meant to executed to completion without being deferred or losing context, unlike SC_THREAD.